# How do I get the line number of a DOMElement?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to get the line number of a DOMElement object in PHP - the documentation says DOMElement extends DOMNode which implements the getLineNo() method, however, when I try to use this method I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::getLineNo()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to PHP 5.3 or higher, see the [documentation](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php). On a side note: dynamically added nodes (i.e. not in the XML document or string on load) will return `0`.